# Neo4J Merge two nodes based on label value

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases, bigdata

I am relatively new to neo4j and I am having some trouble merging my nodes. Maybe I have the concept wrong but here is the problem statement and what I tried to do..

**Problem Statement:** Create a graph by find a match for each user based on the value of a property.

```
Person->  id: user1, movie: lord of the rings
Person->  id: user1, movie: alice in wonderland
Person->  id: user2, movie: star wars
Movie->   name: lord of the rings, genre: Fantasy
Movie->   name: alice in wonderland, genre: Fantasy
Movie->   name: star wars, genre: Fantasy
```

What I want as my output is:

```
user1 -> lord of the rings   
      -> alice in wonderland
user2 -> star wars
```

Instead what I get is:

```
user1 -> lord of the rings
user1 -> alice in wonderland
user2 -> star wars
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
MATCH (a:user),(b:movie)
where a.movieName = b.name
MERGE (a)-[r:matches]->(b)
RETURN r
```

Ideally I want to be able to create a graph where I can see all the connections of a user to the different movies as a one to many connection. I hope this is clear! Any ideas on what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here is kind of a SQL logic, it's not the way Neo4j should be used :). I think you have to change your data model:

Actually, you have:

```
(u:User(name:"", movie:""})
(m:Movie{name:""})
```

Problem is that here, you have a n:1 (or 1:n? never know which one) relationship, meaning that one user can have only one movie.

Neo4j is a graph database, meaning that you can simply do this:

```
(u:User{properties...})-[:MATCHES]->(m:Movie{properties...})
```

Then you'll be able to find every movie for a user, using this request:

```
MATCH (:User{properties...})-[:MATCHES]->(m:Movie) return m;
```

Comment: So do I  need to specify what it matches on? I mean how does it know what to match?

Comment: You have to set the relationships when you create your dataset, you don't have to create a foreignKey relation like you want to do in your question queries.